# Some Widgets ARE showing some are not showing Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

http://ringmastersports.co.uk/

The site is working perfect on mobile but on desktop it works fine few widgets won't showing on frontend. 
i'm working to fix these bugs from last 3 days . don't find any solutions.

this website is made in emgameworld premium magento theme.
slider don't showing and also other things are not showing like tabs. where as few widgets work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have run these commands and in sequence and it solved my problem

php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean and php bin/magento cache:flush